# Execute a function when the colormap changes

Tags: matlab, plot, callback, matlab-guide

I am working on a GUI control MATLAB (2014a) program with a plot window that shows a `contour`-like plot on top of a `pcolor`-based plot.

The users found out, that the `colormap` can be changed by right-clicking the colorbar. This change does however only affect the `pcolor` plot directly, because of the internals of my `contour` functions.

I already found out how to get the changed `colormap` from my axes object and apply it to the `contour` plot, but I still have to manually redo the plot.

Is there any callback that executes once the `colormap` of an `axes` / `figure` object is changed?

I read about [`PropertyChangeCallback`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks), but the `colormap` does not seem to be stored as a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to resort to *undocumented* functionalities to intercept a `colormap` change in Matlab pre-HG2. You can simply attach a listener to the `'PostSet'` event of the property `'Colormap'`.

As a quick example, if your figure is already there, just type:

```
lh = addlistener( h.fig , 'Colormap' , 'PostSet' , @(h,e) disp('cmap changed !') )
```

in the console, and you will get a message every time you change the `colormap`. Note that the event is triggered whether:

- you change the `colormap` entirely to another one (from `jet` to `hsv` for example)
- you change the size of the colormap (the number of division). (ex: `colormap(jet(5))`)
- you use the "*Interactive colormap shift*" gui tool.

---

Note that the event will **not** trigger if you use `caxis`. This command does not change the `colormap` itself but the way some colors are mapped to it. So if you use this command, your `pcolor` will be modified (although the colormap won't). The `caxis` command changes the `CLim` property of the current **`axes`** (not `figure`!). So if you want to detect that, you have to attach a listener to this property on the correct axis. Something like:

```
lh = addlistener( gca , 'CLim' , 'PostSet' , @(h,e) disp('clim changed !') )
```

---

As a more applied example, here's a little demo which will react every time the `colormap` is changed. Since I don't know what you planned to do to your `contour` plot at every change, I just modify a couple of properties just to show that it's doing something. Adjust that to what you need to do.

```
function h = cmap_change_event_demo

%// SAMPLE DATA. create a sample "pcolor" and "contour" plot on a figure
nContour = 10 ;
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(32);
h.fig = figure ;
h.pcol = pcolor(X,Y,Z) ;
hold on;
[~,h.ct] = contour(X,Y,Z,nContour,'k');
h.cb = colorbar
shading interp
colormap( jet(nContour+1) ) %// assign a colormap with only 10+1 colors

%// add the listener to the "Colormap" property
h.lh = addlistener( h.fig , 'Colormap' , 'PostSet' , @cmap_changed_callback )

%// save the handle structure
guidata( h.fig , h )

function cmap_changed_callback(~,evt)
    %//  disp('cmap changed !')

    hf   = evt.AffectedObject ; %// this is the handle of the figure
    cmap = evt.NewValue ;       %// this is the new colormap. Same result than : cmap = get(hf,'Colormap') ;

    h = guidata( hf ) ;         %// to retrieve your contour handles (and all the other handles)
    nColor = size(cmap,1) ;     %// to know how many colors are in there if you want matching contours

    %// or just do something useless
    set(h.ct , 'LineColor' , rand(1,3) )      %// change line color
    set(h.ct , 'LineWidth' , randi([1 5],1) ) %// change line thickness
```

[image: cmap_event_demo]

Comment: Is there a workaround for recent MATLAB release (post HG-2) ?

Comment: @oro777. I'm sorry but I couldn't find one quick way to make it work for the latest Matlab release.